# How to update HTML inside different div tags using Jquery $(this). selector

Tags: jquery, this

If I have a form like this:

```
<form id="form-04">
        <div name="form-status"></div>
        <input name="FromEmail" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text">
        <input name="ToEmail" placeholder="Your Friends Email Address" type="text">
        <textarea name="Message" placeholder="Your Message, 512 characters max." rows="5"></textarea>
        <button style="float: right;" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

If I call $(this). like this:

```
    $('#form-01, #form-02, #form-03, #form-04').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        ..... bla bla bla
    });
});
```

How do I reference the div with the name 'form-status'?  I tried this but I'm at a loss?

```
$("div:first", this).html("HTML txt goes here.");
```

And should I be using the alt attribute instead or something?

PS: I know this would be easy if I would just use an id inside the div tag but I don't have that option.

Comment: False on the using id thing. you should be using classes...

Comment: If you are still facing trouble, let me know so I can help

Comment: @AmmarCSE I'm at my wits end trying to solve this problem or explain it without showing somebody the code I'm actually working on.  Goto: http://dev.chocomap.com/chocolate-e-cards/ and look at the code under the first e-cards form.  I haven't worked on the ajax yet but that's easy, I'm just trying too get the jquery.validate in the footer to work for all these dynamically generated forms.  All I want to do is output the error message the ajax call outputs back into the div below id="ECForm01" without hardcoding the ID into the code.

Comment: @AmmarCSE The line of code I'm working on is on or about line 734.

Comment: @Vince, try changin that line to `$(form).find('[name="form-status"]').html("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);` You cant call `find` as a standalone function. You need some sort of context to start with

Comment: @AmmarCSE OMG Ammar you nailed it, ty so much for helping me figure that out!  It was driving me nuts.

Answer (score 2):

Use [**find()**](http://v)

```
$(this).find('[name="form-status"]').html('HTML txt goes here.');
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was going to leave a comment detailing everything, but you should be using classes not ids.. for all the things...

Your `#form1`,`#form2`,`#form3` .... `#form1000232212100001003` should all be classes of `class="target-form"` or some variation of a name that you think is descriptive enough.

Your code would then be fine to do what you need.

```
$('.target-form').each(function() {
    var form = $(this);
    form.find('[name="form-status"]').html('Yep that worked.');
    form.validate({
        // ..... bla bla bla
    });
});
```

Just to keep with this trend... Even though name is a valid attribute for many things it is not the proper way to do things. I prefer best practice. Use classes.. again... just change `name` to `class` and you're done. Only do this change on `div`, `p`, `span`, `etc...`.. `input`s are fine.